# Add columns labels to a bar plot (Python-matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a list of scores:

```
sincerity_scores=[[0.7386426068589986, 0.03521168088827334, 0.17283997838902623, 0.17978091813696798, 0.46179609926078796, 0.03232785417651009]
```

and I want to obtain a bar plot out of it.

I created the barplot with:

```
x=np.arange(6)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(x, sincerity_scores)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=["CocaCola", "Appletiser", "PepsiMax", "DrPepper", "MountainDew", "Welchs"])
plt.show()
```

but what I get is:
[image]

while I would like the lables of the colums follow the sequence i indicated with as.set_xticklabels. How to do it? Moreover, I would like to set a different colour. Is it possible?

Comment: click on "enter image description here" to see the graph

Comment: Time spent with the [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/index.html) is not wasted. For the impatient user, there is also a [sample gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/index.html) with code to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

change `x` to the list of your labels.

```
sincerity_scores=[0.7386426068589986, 0.03521168088827334, 0.17283997838902623, 0.17978091813696798, 0.46179609926078796, 0.03232785417651009]
x=["CocaCola", "Appletiser", "PepsiMax", "DrPepper", "MountainDew", "Welchs"]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(x, sincerity_scores)
plt.show()
```

This results in this graph:

[image]

color can be set using the color argument in `ax.bar`. like so

```
ax.bar(x, sincerity_scores, color='k')
```

resulting in all bars being black.
[image]

You can change `'k'` for any matplotlib color or any hexcolor code you desire. If you want each bar to have a different color feed a list of codes to color with the same length as you have bars.